# changing the values of countries with flag in select box1 by onchange with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am stuck at one point where i need to populate the country after the ajax resp but it is not showing selected here is the image
[image: if i am selecting the african countries i should get only the united kingdom in select box 2 which i am getting but it is not selected as you can see in the image]

if i am selecting other than african countries i should get all the countries in drop down which i am getting as you can see in the pic but the first one is not selected as you can see in the pic
[image]

here is my code in jquery

```
        var country_data=countries;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ukcountry_ajax.php",
            datatype:"json",
            data:{ country:country_data}
        }).done(function( data ) 
                {

            var final_country=JSON.parse(data);

            var $select=$('#tocurrency');
            $select.find('option').remove();
            $("#tocurrency").select2('data', {id: '', text: ''}); 
            $.each(final_country,function(index) 
            {

                var image=final_country[index].final_image;
                var name=final_country[index].countryname;
                $('#tocurrency').append("<option value="+image+">"+name+"</option>");

            });

        });
```

can any body suggest where i am wrong code is wrkng fine in ie,chrome and FF but not getting selected the first country in the select box as it is showing empty
TIA

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one, but I don't understand anything about your speech on flags and dropdown at the begining of your question... Maybe you could post the html code instead of pictures...

Comment: i am asking that after on change in select box 1 depending on that country i am populating the countries in select box 2 i am getting the response correctly but the first country is not selected in box 2 and showing empty- hope i am clear now- Junius Rendel 3

Comment: indeed, it's clearer but the intial html code would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this by `first child` element as a selected value.
Remove this line

`$("#tocurrency").select2('data', {id: '', text: ''});`

and update your `each` loop like this

```
$.each(final_country,function(index) 
{
        var image=final_country[index].final_image;
        var name=final_country[index].countryname;
        if(index==0)
        {
            $('#tocurrency').append("<option selected value="+image+">"+name+"</option>");

        }
        else{
        $('#tocurrency').append("<option value="+image+">"+name+"</option>");
        }

    });

$("#tocurrency").select2('data', {id: $('#tocurrency option:first-child').val(), text:$('#tocurrency option:first-child').text() });
```

I hope it will help. Thanks